# Bitwise combination as a comparison tool

Tags: if-statement, bit-manipulation

I am writing a `C++` function which has a print flag. I want to print different messages using this flag. I thought of this flag to take three different binary values and to print different messages depending on its value.

```
flag == 000
    printf "flag is 0"

flag == 010
    printf "flag is 1"

flag == 100
    printf "flag is 2"
```

How can I compare the value of this flag such that I can have the following output:

```
flag ==011 
    printf "flag is 0"
    printf "flag is 1"

flag ==101 
    printf "flag is 0"
    printf "flag is 2"

flag ==111 
    printf "flag is 0"
    printf "flag is 1"
    printf "flag is 2"
```

I know that I can add more `if-blocks` to do this task, which does not look professional. Could someone help me find the proper way and avoid writing unnecessary `if-block`s?

Comment: Did you mean: flag == 001 printf "flag is 0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
 char flags[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08 };
 int i;
 for(i = 0 ; i < sizeof(flags) ; i++ )
   if(flag & flags[i])
     printf("flag is %i\n",i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through and do a bitwise and (`&`) with each bit in `flags`. This means you don't have to add more if/else blocks if you want to check more bits. e.g.:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int flags = 7;
    int n = 3;  // change this to however many bits you want to check

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (flags & 1<<i) {
            printf("flag is %d\n", i);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want to print out which bits are set in the flag.  To do that you can use a loop and a right shift.

```cpp
for(int bit = 0; flag > 0; ++bit, flag >>= 1) {
    if(flag & 1)
        printf("flag is %d\n", bit);
}
```

Note that this will destroy the value of `flag` so make a copy of it if you want to use it again later.